# I am trying to return an x and y value to set an entities spawn in my game. What am I missing here?

Tags: java, game-engine

I am trying to set the spawn point for the player to be at a specific tile, but I am not sure how to accomplish that. Here is the relevant code:

From Player class:

```
public Player(Level level, int x, int y, InputHandler input) {
    super(level, "Player", x, y, 1);
    this.input = input;
}
```

From Game class:

```
public int spawnX = Level.getSpawnTileX();
public int spawnY = Level.getSpawnTileY(getY());
```

This is in my init():

```
player = new Player(level, spawnX, spawnY, input);
```

This is from my Level class:

```
public static int getSpawnTileX(int x){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x1 = 0; x1 < width; x1++){
            for(Tile t : Tile.tiles){
            if(t.getLevelColor() == 0xff00ff00){
                return x1;                  
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
public static int getSpawnTileY(int y){
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for(int y1 = 0; y1 < height; y1++){
            for(Tile t : Tile.tiles){
            if(t != null && t.getLevelColor() == 0xff00ff00){
                return y1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
            }
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

And this is from my Tile class:

```
public static final Tile SPAWN = new BasicTile(3, 3, 0, Colors.get(-1, 141, 131, -1), 0xffff0000);
public int getLevelColor(){
    return levelColor;
}
```

Tile class:

```
public abstract class Tile {

public static final Tile[] tiles = new Tile[256];
public static final Tile VOID = new BasicSolidTile(0, 0, 0, Colors.get(000, -1, -1, -1), 0xff000000);
public static final Tile STONE = new BasicSolidTile(1, 1, 0, Colors.get(-1, 333, -1, -1), 0xff555555);
public static final Tile GRASS = new BasicTile(2, 2, 0, Colors.get(-1, 131, 141, -1), 0xff00ff00);
public static final Tile SPAWN = new BasicTile(3, 3, 0, Colors.get(-1, 141, 131, -1), 0xffff0000);
```

If more code is needed for clarification, I would be happy to try to provide it.  Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that even with me trying to get the spawn point to change to a location defined by the map, it isn't, despite my best efforts.

Comment: Okay, since I almost have the solution (I got the values for the x and y coords of the SPAWN tile to be recorded), do I post the solution here when I get the whole solution, or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
        for(Tile t : Tile.tiles){
        if(t.getLevelColor() == 0xff00ff00){
            return x1;                  
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
        }
```

It should be this:

```
        for(Tile t : Tile.tiles){
        if(t.getLevelColor() == 0xff00ff00){
            return x1;                  
        }
        }
```

The issue is that it only checks the first value in `Tile.tiles`.  If it isn't the correct value, it immediately returns 0.  The change I show above makes it actually continue, and check the rest of the tiles.

Comment: Okay, but I had that before and it still wasn't working.

Comment: Looking at more of your code, it might also relate to creating your spawn tile with `0xffff0000` as the color, but checking for `0xff00ff00`.

Comment: That was the levelColor code for GRASS. I was just trying to get the player to spawn anywhere but at 0, 0.  Even with it being 0xffff0000, it doesn't do it.

Comment: Does `Tile.tiles` contain `SPAWN`?

Comment: I guess not, it is in the original post.

Comment: That might be another thing to check - if it isn't in Tile.tiles, it won't be found in the loop.

Comment: When I try to replace Tile.tiles with Tile.SPAWN, I get this:  Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

Comment: What I meant was something like this: `Tile.tiles[0] = Tile.SPAWN;`.

Comment: Where exactly do you mean for that to go? In the for loop, or the Tile class?

Comment: In the tile class, or really anywhere, for instance in the level constructor.  (Though not in the for loop; that could cause issues)

Comment: Okay. Should I move this to a chat? Because that is not really working.